# Accessing current Activity from any place

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm writing application which needs in some places access to current `Activity`. So I have written code which gives access by calling `Application.getApplication().getCurrentActivity()`. I'm wondering what are possible drawbacks of such solution and is it a good practice for writing Android applications? Can someone share his one experience?

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

    private static volatile Application INSTANCE;

    private ApplicationLifecycleListener mApplicationLifecycleListener;

    public static Application application() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        INSTANCE = this;
        initApplicationLifecycleListener();
    }

    private void initApplicationLifecycleListener() {
        mApplicationLifecycleListener = new ApplicationLifecycleListener();
       registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(mApplicationLifecycleListener);
    }

    public Activity getCurrentActivity() {
       return mApplicationLifecycleListener.getCurrentActivityReference().get();
    }

    private class ApplicationLifecycleListener implements android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {

        private WeakReference<Activity> mCurrentActivityReference;

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {
            mCurrentActivityReference = new WeakReference<>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
            mCurrentActivityReference = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {}

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {}

        public WeakReference<Activity> getCurrentActivityReference() {
            return mCurrentActivityReference;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you need acces to `Activity` in some places why you just dont pass `Activity` to these "places".

Comment: Maybe because I don't know which activity is resumed now?

Comment: Good practice is to use `startActivity()/startActivityForResult()` and [Activities Back Stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack.html) (flags like `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` etc.). Or even better "convert" Your `Activity` into `Fragment` and use it in all "some places'.

Comment: "is it a good practice for writing Android applications?" -- IMHO, no.

Comment: You are telling yours opinion without explanation.